# nginx rewrite: everything but empty base url

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

After about 2 hours of googling and trying various things out, I turn to you for help.

Task:
Rewrite the blank url to something, and everything else to something different in nginx.

So, if I navigate to subdomain.somedomain.tld, I want to get served the index.php, and if I go to subdomain.somedomain.tld/BlAaA, I get redirected to index.php?url=BlAaA. Exceptions are files under /img, /include, and the index.php themselves. They don't get rewritten.

The second part works already, as does the whitelist, but I can't figure out or find something to accomplish the whole idea.

The working part:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  subdomain.domain.tld;

  location / {
    include php.conf;
    root    /srv/http/somefolder/someotherfolder/;

    if ( $uri !~ ^/(index\.php|include|img) ){
      rewrite /(.*) /index.php?url=$1 last;
    }

    index   index.php;
  }
}
```

The answer provided by @pablo-b almost solved my problem.
Only two problems persist with this approach: 1: PHP-FPM now needs to have the extensions of the files under /include/ (e.g. style.css, background.jpg) set in /etc/php/php-fpm.conf under security.limit_extensions. My original php.conf worked along the lines of

```
location ~ \.php {
    #DO STUFF
}
```

which nginx doesn't like, since it kinda overwrites the location /index.php part from your suggestion. I can work around that, though, given enough time.

2: $request_uri yields "/whatever", not "whatever" as value to my url= parameter. I can parse the "/" out in my php code, for sure, but my original solution didn't add the leading "/". Any elegant way to solve this?

Comment: I added removing the `/` part, although it doesn't seems very elegant (performance wise, the mapping only happens when `$uri_without_slash` is accesed). As for 1), you could just replace `location = /index.php` with `location ~ \.php`, but it will serve without redirecting any url containing the string `.php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest avoiding `if` and working with different locations making use of the precedence related to the pattern matching methods used ([docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)):

```
#blank url
location = / {
    return 302 http://subdomain.domain.tld/index.php;
}

#just /index.php
location = /index.php {
    include common_settings;
}

#anything starting with /img/
location ^~ /img/ {
    include common_settings;
}

#anything starting with /include/
location ^~ /include/ {
    include common_settings;
}

#everything else
location / {
    return 302 http://subdomain.domain.tld/index.php?url=$uri_without_slash;
}
```

And in a separated config file called `common_settings`:

```
include php.conf;
root    /srv/http/somefolder/someotherfolder/;
index   index.php;
```

EDIT: Added removal of first slash in url:

In your conf, outside any `server` directive:

```
map $request_uri $uri_without_slash {
    ~^/(?P<trailing_uri>.*)$ $trailing_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works wonderfully! Just as an FYI for other ppl who have this problem: It could have been solved by my original way if I had just checked for $_GET['url'] == '' in my page itself. But this solution is way cleaner.